# Add Broadcast Upload Extension in an existing app

Tags: ios, swift, jitsi

I want to add a `Broadcast Upload Extension` to an existing swift native app. This extension is used for `capturing the contents of the user's screen` like `screen sharing`.

**Purpose:**

I am adding `Jitsi Meet SDK` for video calling in my app. And this SDK requires a `broadcast upload extension` to enable the screen sharing option.

**What I have tried:**

I tried to add a `broadcast upload extension` with a new app and copy all the configuration into my existing app.

Steps of copying configuration from new app to existing app:

1. Copy files `Atomic.swift`, `DarwinNotificationCenter.swift`, `SocketConnection.swift` from broadcast extension folder of screen sharing sample given in `Jitsi Meet SDK` sample project. [Here](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-sdk-samples/tree/master/ios/swift-screensharing/JitsiSDKScreenSharingTest/Broadcast%20Extension)
2. Added `.entitlements` file as per the above link of `Jitsi Meet SDK sample`
3. Added the group key in the `.entitlements` file in the main project folder group

`.entitlements` file In main project folder group :

```
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.com.jitsi.example-screensharing.appgroup</string>
    </array>
```

5. Copy the `NSExtension` key and its content from the new app to the existing one in `info.plist` file.
6. Give permissions to the `microphone, camera & local network` in the existing app in `info.plist` file.
7. Add keys `RTCScreenSharingExtension` & `RTCAppGroupIdentifier`  in the existing app in `info.plist` file.

`info.plist` (point 5):

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.broadcast-services-upload</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SampleHandler</string>
        <key>RPBroadcastProcessMode</key>
        <string>RPBroadcastProcessModeSampleBuffer</string>
    </dict>
```

`info.plist` (point 6):

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This will allow you to use microphone to record audio messages and join ${PRODUCT_NAME} meetings</string>
 
   <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Local network access is needed for P2P connections.</string>
   
 <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This lets you do things like take a photo and set it as your profile picture or share photos and videos with other team members within your workspace.
</string>
```

`info.plist` (point 7):

```
<key>RTCScreenSharingExtension</key>
<string>com.jitsi.example-screensharing.broadcast.extension</string>
<key>RTCAppGroupIdentifier</key>
<string>group.com.jitsi.example-screensharing.appgroup</string>
```

**Error:**

Getting an error in an existing app that

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name-cgxqvnvmumzlucbokufvjzcnobpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project-name.app/Info.plist':
1) Target 'project-name' (project 'project-name') has copy command from '/Users/Username/workspace/github/project-name/project-name/Info.plist' to '/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name-cgxqvnvmumzlucbokufvjzcnobpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project-name.app/Info.plist'
2) Target 'project-name' (project 'project-name') has process command with output '/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name-cgxqvnvmumzlucbokufvjzcnobpn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project-name.app/Info.plist'
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Arjun Unfortunately, no. I haven't found the solution and moved to other things. I will post an answer if I do.